# How can I make this pyramid with C++ to look like my example?

Tags: c++

I would like to create this pyramid with C++, but I am a bit stuck. Can I get some help to complete my example?

```
6*****
*6****
**6***
***6**
****6*
*****6
```

```
int num1;
cout<<"please enter a size between 1-9: "<<flush;
cin>>num1;

for(int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
{
    cout <<num1;
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        cout<<"*";
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

```
6*
6**
6***
6****
6*****
6******
```

Comment: You probably need a for-loop before cout << num1 that prints the initial stars.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can handle this:

- use 2 separate loops, one for the stars in front of the number, and another loop for the stars behind the number, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;

    cout << "please enter a size between 1-9: ";
    cin >> num1;

    for(int i = 0; i < num1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            cout << "*";

        cout << num1;

        for(int j = num1-1; j > i; --j)
            cout << "*";

        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/lOJLkY)

- use a single loop that conditionally decides whether to output a star or the number depending on which position is currently being output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;

    cout << "please enter a size between 1-9: ";
    cin >> num1;

    for(int i = 0; i < num1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < num1; ++j)
        {
            if (j == i)
                cout << num1;
            else
                cout << "*";
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/NuS1Cg)

Comment: @amchacon fixed.

Comment: ******7
*****7*
****7**
***7***
**7****
*7*****
7******  how do i write this inclusively this code worked well

Answer (score 0):

You need asterisks before the number and after the number. So, let's expand your idea:

```
int num1;
cout<<"please enter a size between 1-9: "<<flush;
cin>>num1;

for(int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
{
    //Asterisks before the number
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout<<"*";
    }

    cout <<num1;

    //Asterisks after the number
    for(int j = i; j < num1; j++)
    {
        cout<<"*";
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

There is a little improve that you could do: Refactorize in functions:

```
void writeRow(int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        std::cout << "*";
}

// Some code...

for(int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
{
    //Asterisks before the number
    writeRow(i);

    cout <<num1;

    //Asterisks after the number
    writeRow(num1-i);

    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I would rename `writeRow()` to something more meaningful, like `writeStars()` or `writeAsterisks()`.

Comment: this worked how would i do the opposite this problem has me confused your code works by the way. ******7
*****7*
****7**
***7***
**7****
*7*****
7******

Answer (score 0):

You can create the entire string for each row by using the `std::string` constructor that takes a count and a character.

Basically here is the pattern:

1. Print 0 stars, the number 6, then `num-1` stars.
2. Print 1 star, the number 6, then `num-2` stars.
3. Print 2 stars, the number 6, then `num-3` stars.

   etc...

So the pattern is to build a string that consists of the stars before, the number 6, then the stars after, and for each row, you increment the stars before, and decrement the stars after.

So here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int num1 = 6;
  int stars_before = 0;
  int stars_after = num1 - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < num1; ++i)
     std::cout << std::string(stars_before++, '*') << '6' << std::string(stars_after--, '*') << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
6*****
*6****
**6***
***6**
****6*
*****6
```